# P-MOSFET failing

Tags: mosfet, inductive, failure

[image: Updated schematic]

I am using this solution to drive a large (huge) relay on a boat.

The system works well for months on end, but eventually the MOSFET (T2) dies suddenly.

I have modified the schematic to include the modification suggested by Jack Creasey and others (circled in RED, not part of original design), as well as a further explanation as to how the system is wired to battery ground to illustrate why the typical snubber diode may be inadequate (it dissipates back-EMF to battery ground through a 4-ohm wire).

Simulations suggest that with this cable resistance back-EMF may push LOCAL_GND down to -20 V with respect to BATTERY_GND, the controller would see 34 V and fry.

I am hoping to find suggestions on the correct way to protect the MOSFET in this situation.

I am not able to make modifications to anything outside of the gray box and no strong GND connection is available in this part of the system.

`12VDC` is the battery voltage and may vary depending on load, generator output, other loads switching, etc. Typically 11-14.4 volts.

The relay draws approximately 6 A from PULSE_OUT, but I have never had access to the actual relay to perform measurements on its inductance or behavior when switched on or off.

Because the relay is bistable and requires only a pulse to turn on, PULSE_TTL is driven with 200 ms pulses at 3.3 V. These pulses are typically very infrequent, but they can occur every 5 seconds worst case. Another identical circuit drives the turn off coil in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simple, you need a diode across the output wire to the relay.

When you turn the current to the relay OFF you will get a large negative back EMF spike on the drain of the FET ([IRFR5305](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfr5305pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535632522820ff)). The spike will likely far exceed the 55 V rating for the FET, and although the FET will avalanche this may not provide the required protection depending on the energy stored in the relay coil.

Connect the diode like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyyFtP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While I've shown a BAT54 here, almost any power diode will do. Even an 1N4001 would be more than adequate.

**Update:**

Your update to the question posed what problems long thin (small gauge) wire to the really would pose. I would suggest that there is *no problem*.

If the wiring is sufficient to carry a peak current of 6 A to drive the relay, then current at turn OFF cannot be higher than 6 A, and will fall exponentially after the OFF drive transition.

If you are really concerned about your configuration then I'd suggest the following configuration where the FET is kept on to dissipate the inductive energy.

[image: Schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKuARO.png)</sup>

[image]

The waveforms would look like the above, but I just used a dummy L limiting to 6 A to demonstrate.

In the schematic above, the components in the box result in the FET being turned on at about 34 V back EMF from the relay. This is all reference to the +12 V supply, so is not impacted in any way by the wiring. Allowing the back EMF to develop to 34 V means the FET never sees anything above 44 V (12 V + 34 V) so comfortably within its 55 V rating.
And before anyone asks ….D2 does not clamp during the back EMF, the voltage on the gate will be just enough (V<sub>(GS)</sub>) to cause M1 to conduct sufficiently to clamp the drain voltage.

**NOTE:** Your base resistor to Q1 is too high. You should lower this to about 2700 ohms.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I understand how back-EMF works (and I typically do put in this diode) but in this case I did not for two reasons:
1) i thought the MOSFET avalanche would take care of the problem better than a diode - is this completely wrong in this case?
2) I do not have access to a strong GND connection at the MOSFET device side (0.5mm²/AWG20 for GND vs 2.5/AWG14 for 12V)

Is there other ways of safely dissipating back-EMF into +12V such as a zener diode gate to drain, or should I not worry about the wire guage?

Comment: Forget wire gauge ….put the diode right at your FET or if it's easier right across the relay. There is some technical difference in placement but it will not impact you.

Comment: I am not able to modify anything outside of the device, so putting it on the relay side is out of the question. Of course I would put it in right next to the FET, but this means all of the back-emf energy will be dissipated to GND through a rather thin and long wire. If the resistance/inductance of this wire is too high, the diode will not be very effective is what I'm thinking. It would be as if D1 (your schematic) was connected to GND through about 4 ohm worst case - will this really be enough to add significant protection?

Comment: The long wire makes no real difference.

Comment: I have updated my original question to reflect exactly where the weak GND connection is present and how it affects the snubber diode. Perhaps you are saying that 4 ohms is simply insignificant in this case?

Comment: I did experiments with an iron slab in my test load to up the inductance and the original suggestion does indeed result in overvoltage at the Controller (not just in simulations). Your second suggestion though, wow - thank you so much for taking the time to explain and illustrate. This is in line with the idea I had in my first comment regarding zener gate to drain - it simulates beautifully and I firmly believe this will work very well. Note: R4 was a typo, is 10k for >25mA+ Ic with a 2N3904 (good guess btw). I should go improve my understanding of FET avalanche handling... Again, thank you!

Comment: @RonaldMcFüglethorn  If your wiring really is 4 Ohms, then that IS significant. It has no impact at all on the back-emf but would be a limit to the current that could flow with the FET ON. If it really is 4 Ohms then you can't have more than 3A flowing (and that is with the relay shorted out!!), so I really doubt it is that high.

Comment: The wiring for 12V is absolutely not 4 ohm, this is where power flows TO the coil through the FET. The wiring to GND on the other hand is weak. Therefore I worry about dissipating back-EMF to GND. I tried explaining this with a resistor in my current schematic - no resistors drawn on +12V or on PULSE_OUT (in reality < 56mOhm). The relay itself also has good GND wiring. The device replaces a mechanical switch 10m away, 3mm² wire for relay coil positive was in place. To power the controller a thin GND wire was added. In reality this wire is about 1 ohm max, 4 ohm is the worst case spec.

Comment: This maybe explains the situation https://imgur.com/a/BhvsJe6

Comment: Yeah, I suck at drawing, sry :D There just isn't any solid GND available for "historical" reasons. No good path to send the back-EMF except 12V. First time I've ever come across this situation so I was unsure if turning the FET on to shunt the energy was even a valid solution. But you gave me some confidence in trying again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch off an inductive load (your large relay) you may well get a large voltage spike. This will eventually damage the transistor if not immediately.  You do not appear to have included a snubber network across the MOSFET (12VDC to PULSE_OUT) which will protect it. I suggest you read the appropriate [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber) as a start, then google "Snubber network" for more detailed articles and design notes.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understand back-EMF and snubber diodes and I typically include these. I had ignorantly thought/hoped that in this case the MOSFET would avalanche and adequately handle the back-EMF without the addition of an external diode, but I think you are correct that I need stronger protection. I have updated my question to include your suggestion as well an an explanation on how GND is tied to the system, which I believe presents a problem for the typical snubber solution. I would love your take on this.